# Altium 22 or above - copying part parameters from supplier information into part for easier part creation

Tags: components, altium, library

I have some parts that show up in altium 22 or above (using 24), but if the footprint and other information isn't there, it needs to be created. (NOTE: if you right click on the supplier there is no drop down box that lets you add the part, but you can still see the parameters) The best way is to clone an existing part and then add in the information from the suppliers. One problem I have is this process is done manually for each parameter.

Is there a way to copy parameters from a part in the manufacturer part search to the parameters in a part?
[image]

Comment: You may want to try database [linking](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/666706/altium-correct-way-to-handle-multiple-variants-of-the-same-ic/666715#666715).